# Transfer Office Language Packs between different installations of Office

Tags: microsoft-office, language-pack

I have Microsoft Office installed in different languages on different systems. One version is English and the other one is German. The English version does not support spell checking of German documents - I would need to buy an additional [Office Language Pack](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/language/) to do this. The German installation of Office is of course able to spell check German documents. 
The Office Language Pack for German is part of the package.

Is it (a) possible and (b) legal to take the German Office Language Pack from one installation and transfer it to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After earning the tumbleweed badge for this question I am finally able to answer it myself. You can simply take the system with the English version installed, start the installation of the German Office suite, click an "Add feature" and select the Option "German".

The English interface stays untouched but the German language checking feature is available afterwards. Problem solved.